# Where does Windows 7 put files saved to Program Files

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have an old program that saves its files to Program Files.  We are updating it to run properly on Windows 7.  The problem is that we now can't find our saved files. Windows 7 allowed our program to save to program files, but obviously put the files somewhere else.  We can't find that 'somewhere else'.  Does anybody know where Windows 7 places its files when we save in Program Files?

Update:
We've looked in program files, in program files (x86), we've used Windows Explorer search function to try and find the directory name.  Nothing works, but when we check to see if the directory we are making already exists in our application, we find it and put up our error dialog box.

Comment: Not sur that question fits here but it's a very good one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\[APPNAME]`

Comment: Found them...so why does Windows Explorer search not find them?

Comment: Explorer search is crap (Only searches content of known file types and only the full drive when you twist its arm) Try Agent Ransack or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `program files (86)` if your application is a 32 bit app. The place they should be saved is in the users directory though (or even better, give the user the choice of where to save).

Comment: No, I've looked there.  Its really silly, my app can see the files I've put there, but I can't find the files anywhere.